# rsyslog send log over RELP fails

Tags: logging, tcp, rsyslog

I am trying to send a log file to a server using rsyslog RELP. The configuration on the client is as follows:

> /etc/rsyslog.d/00-userlog.conf

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="omrelp")

input(type="imfile"
      File="/home/user/user.log"
      escapeLF="on"
      Tag="applog"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local7")

template(name="app_tem" type="string" string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg%")
*.* :omrelp:192.168.1.90:20514;app_tem
```

And the configuration on the server:

> /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
module(load="imrelp")
input(type="imrelp" port="20514" maxDataSize="10k")

$template customFormat, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/Users/%SYSLOGTAG%.log"
*.* ?;customFormat
```

With this configuration when the user's log changes, the log file is not sent. Also on the server in the file I get several errors:

```
input module name 'imrelp' is unknown
parameter 'maxDataSize' not known
parameter 'port' not known
```

I don't know what's happening since I follow the imrelp and omrelp documentation and it doesn't work well for me. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I no longer have 'imrelp' errors but I still don't receive the log file...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server system, the `imrelp.so` library may not be installed by default with rsyslog. For example, on debian or fedora you may need to install package `rsyslog-relp` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I no longer have those errors but I still don't receive the log file I need ...

Comment: rsyslogd will only send new data added to the `user.log` file. Or you can find and remove the state file which remembers how much has been read, then restart rsyslogd. I'm not sure of the default state file name, nor where to find it. Look in `/var /usr/var /run` perhaps. Also, there should be no semi-colon in `*.* ?;customFormat` on the server.